# JTable not update from input data there are in other class after press button

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Please help  me to resolve a simple problem ( I hope). I cant find an answer for this one so I've decided to write post.

Description of the problem:

I have one frame JFrame FormOne which include a table and a second frame JDialog there is also a table.(data from this table will be transmitted through the ArrayList to the table in FormOne) for this example, I created an ArrayList with data.Thera are in myObject, 
when I press button data should be displayed in the table in FormOne but in my case create new window with data myObject. If I remove the init variable then, 
I get  following problem:

"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

below I put part of code  FormOne

```
 public class FormOne extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public FormOne() {
    initComponents();


}
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    DialogOne startDialog =new DialogOne(this, true);
    startDialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

part code of DialogOne:

```
  public class DialogOne extends javax.swing.JDialog {



public DialogOne(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();

}


 public void dane(){

    noweDane=new FormOne(); // if a remove  then is error
    model=(DefaultTableModel) noweDane.Tabela.getModel(); 

    ArrayList myObject = new ArrayList<Object>();
    myObject.add("test");
    myObject.add("win");
    myObject.add("1");
    myObject.add("2");

   model.addRow(myObject.toArray());

   // it create new Frame ( include data which I want to see) but I want to put value         
   //to  exist table

   noweDane.setVisible(true); 


}
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    this.dane();




}
```

Thx for any suggest or help...

Comment: What line does the exception occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "(data from this table will be transmitted through the ArrayList to the table in FormOne)"

This is unnecessary. Instead pass the `TableModel` to the dialog class so they can access/reference the same model. I have a feeling the fact that you're creating a new `FormOne` is related to the NullPointerException, and this is how you are trying to access the table/model. Try something like this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
    DialogOne startDialog =new DialogOne(this, true, model);
    startDialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

You can see I passed the model to the dialog

```
public class DialogOne extends JDialog {
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private JTable table;

    public DialogOne(JFrame frame, boolean modal, DefaultTableModel model) {
        super(frame, modal);
        this.model = model;
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(model);
    }

    public void dane() {
        ...
        model.addRow(...);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE** Example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class SameTableModel {
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    public SameTableModel() {
        String[] cols = { "Col One", "Col Two" };
        model = new DefaultTableModel(cols, 0);
        table = new JTable(model);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton("Open Dialog");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DialogOne dialog = new DialogOne(frame, true, model);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new SameTableModel();
            }
        });
    }
}

class DialogOne extends JDialog {
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField fieldOne;
    private JTextField fieldTwo;

    public DialogOne(JFrame owner, boolean modal, DefaultTableModel model) {
        super(owner, modal);
        this.model = model;

        table = new JTable(model);
        button = createButton();
        JPanel fieldPanel = createFieldPanel();
        fieldPanel.add(button);

        JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();
        eastPanel.add(fieldPanel);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
    }

    private JPanel createFieldPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        fieldOne = new JTextField(12);
        fieldTwo = new JTextField(12);
        panel.add(fieldOne);
        panel.add(fieldTwo);
        return panel;
    }

    private JButton createButton() {
        JButton jbt = new JButton("Add Row");
        jbt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text1 = fieldOne.getText();
                String text2 = fieldOne.getText();
                model.addRow(new Object[] { text1, text2});
                fieldOne.setText("");
                fieldTwo.setText("");
            }
        });
        return jbt;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, but the problem is with data which there are in second class ( JDialog) I want show it in the table in class one. Accordnig to my example code button in class FormOne start frame Jdialog where there are data which I want to send to tabel there is in FormOne class if I create new object in JDialog (second class) and add model from first class I get it, but in the new Frame. How I can get update  table in class JFrame FormOne when I click button in class DialogOne

Comment: I showed you. Use the same model from the FormOne as you do in the dialog. Use table.setModel(model) in the dialog the set the model to the model passed in from the FormOne

Comment: Basically use the same set of data from the same table model. There's no need to have a separate table model for each table.

Comment: I try use your suggest, and I'll share info... on dashboard... :) Thx for your time and help...